# Stored Procedure to Insert Two Tables with Relationship?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I was trying to insert a new row into two tables which has a relationship between. I wrote the stored procedure as follows.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE InsertUserProfile
(
    @UserID varchar(10),
    @Pass varchar(50),
    @Enabled int,
    @Permission int,
    @Rank int,
    @FName varchar(50),
    @LName varchar(50),
    @Phone varchar(50),
    @Email1 varchar(50),
    @Email2 varchar(50)
)
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO tbl_user_login VALUES (@UserID, @Pass, @Enabled, @Permission, @Rank)
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN 
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END


INSERT INTO tbl_user_profile VALUES (@FName, @LName, @Phone, @Email1, @Email2)
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END

COMMIT
```

**From this follow ASP.NET Code**

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertUserProfile", sqlConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", DbType.String).Value = txtUserID.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", DbType.String).Value = txtPass.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Enabled", DbType.Int32).Value = 1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Permission", DbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPermission.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rank", DbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRank.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", DbType.String).Value = txtFName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", DbType.String).Value = txtLName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", DbType.String).Value = txtPhone.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email1", DbType.String).Value = txtEmail1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email2", DbType.String).Value = txtEmail2.Text;

        sqlConn.Open();
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConn.Close();
```

But I'm getting the following error.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with
>   the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_tbl_user_profile_tbl_user_login".
>   The conflict occurred in database "My
>   DB Location", table
>   "dbo.tbl_user_login", column 'ID'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

I'm new to Stored Procedures so any suggestions how should I fix it so that I could insert data into two tables?

**TABLE SCHEMA**

```
tbl_user_login

ID (int) 
UserID (varchar10) 
Pass (varchar50) 
Enabled (int) 
Permission (int) 
Rank (int)

tbl_user_profile

ID (int)
FName (varchar50)
LName (varchar50)
Phone (varchar50)
Email1 (varchar50)
Email2 (varchar50)
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables? I don't see any common column between them . . .

Comment: @Richard Its "ID" which is the Auto Increment in both tables.

Comment: Can u share the schema of both tables ?

Comment: @TechGiant, Schema added to the question.

Comment: You can see my last post i have mentioned. You need to set id column as identity and then insert values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> @Richard Its "ID" which is the Auto Increment in both tables.

Having an auto-increment (`IDENTITY`) act as a primary key is fine, but using it as a foreign key is dangerous, since you can't really guarantee that they will always be in sync; any rollback could leave them broken (rollback does not undo identity increments, as this would affect other SPIDs). Also, any thread-race between two concurrent `INSERT`s will be in jeopardy.

The correct approach here is to query `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the first insert, and use that in the `INSERT` to the second table; i.e. in the second table you *tell* it the value. Note that since `@@ERROR` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` are floating values, you should query them both directly after the first `INSERT`:

```
SELECT @Error = @@ERROR, @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: I agree with Marc, not only is it dangerous, it doesn't make too much sense, in most cases. A relationship usually signifies they are _related_ in some meaningful way, and most often an indentity value doesn't really have "meaning", it's just a primary key, a way to gaurantee a unique record. Try to find some relationship between the tables that is meaningful. That being said, sometimes it is appropriate for an identity to be a foreign key. (there are no hard and fast rules).

Comment: Should I use UserID from tbl_user_login as the FK in tbl_user_profile?

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the auto-incremented value that you get when you insert into the first table, tbl_user_login. After you capture it, you need to use it to insert into the second table.

```
DECLARE @ID int

BEGIN TRANSACTION 
INSERT INTO tbl_user_login VALUES (@UserID, @Pass, @Enabled, @Permission, @Rank)

SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()    
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN      
    ROLLBACK     
    RETURN 
END   

INSERT INTO tbl_user_profile VALUES (@ID, @FName, @LName, @Phone, @Email1, @Email2) 

IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BEGIN     
    ROLLBACK     
    RETURN 
END  

COMMIT
```

Comment: First, `@@IDENTITY` is dangerous (it is impacted by triggers etc); `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` should **always** be used instead. Second; when you read `@@IDENTITY` you probably threw away the `@@ERROR` you were checking for.

Comment: To add to this, the ID column in tbl_user_profile should not be an auto-incrementing IDENTITY column.

Answer (score -1):

```
Create Table tbl_user_login
(
**ID INT Identity(1,1),**
UserID varchar10,
Pass varchar50 ,
Enabled int,
Permission int ,
Rank int
);
```

Make ID column as Identity(1,1) that will be auto incremented column and that will solve your problem. Make it in both tables.

Comment: You'd probably end up with different userid's in both tables

Comment: Nopes if u insert values through a stored procedure at the same time so ID would be same. Identity column auto increment values and would be same in both tables.

Comment: But they can easily get out of synch whenever a transaction is aborted, or multiple calls to the procedure are made at the same time

Comment: Yeah you are right the thing is he's looking for a solution why it's not inserting values so i think if he would try this then he can be able to insert values and then he can better understand the problem why he was facing this ?