# Junction Table, Insert and Select

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, relational-database

[image]

I'm learning this on my own, and i've reached a point where I want to insert new Categories and new Countries but I don't know how to do that exactly.

For instance to add a new category I do the following:

```
public int Insert()
{
    string sqlString = "INSERT INTO Categories (name, image) VALUES (@Name, @Image);";
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new
       SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OahuDB"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", this.Name);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", this.Image);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    int x = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection.Close();
    sqlConnection.Dispose();
    return x;
}
```

But how should I insert the relationship between both tables and then retrieve data based on the junction table?

If you could give examples and good tutorials on this or if you could elaborate a little bit.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Why don't you use stored procedures and call it through C#. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762942/stored-procedure-to-insert-two-tables-with-relationship) is an example and to know more about junction tables please refer to [this](http://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/understanding-a-sql-junction-table/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send SQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO Categories (name, image) VALUES (@Name, @Image);
SELECT scope_identity() as NewCategoryId;
```

This will return the ID of the newly added category as a rowset.  You can retrieve the new ID using the familiar `ExecuteReader()`:

```
using (var read = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    read.Read();
    int newCategoryId = (int) read["NewCategoryId"];
}
```

Or even shorter with `ExecuteScalar()`:

```
int newId = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

And by the way, consider wrapping your connection in `using`:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("...connection string...")
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    var sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    ...
}
```

That helps guard against connection leaks.  It's always possible that one of the `Execute` methods throws an exception, whether it's a timeout or a network issue.

Comment: so then after retrieving the id i would insert again in the junction table?

Comment: Yes, and if you'd need a new country, of course you'd have to insert that first