# SQL Server stored procedure to insert in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I have 2 tables, `custlogin` and `custinfo`:

`custlogin`:

```
custid int primary key auto notnull
custusename varchar(25)
custpassword varchar(50)
```

`custinfo`:

```
custid foriegnkey custlogin.custid ondelete set NULL
custfirstname varchar(25)
custlastname  varchar(25)
custaddress   varchar(100)
```

I want to write a stored procedure which will insert into both tables

More precisely, insert into `custlogin` with `custusername custpassword`, which would return `custid` for use as foreign key for `custinfo`.

I have searched much but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: You couldn't have searched that hard - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318924/how-do-i-insert-into-two-tables-all-at-once-in-a-stored-procedure

Comment: check in this link -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762942/stored-procedure-to-insert-two-tables-with-relationship

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It will be something like below. You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the last autogenerated ID withing the scope which is this stored proc in this case:

```
create procedure NameOfYourProcedureHere
as
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    insert into custlogin(custusename, custpassword) 
        values ('','') -- put values here (from parameters?)

    insert into custinfo(custid, custfirstname, custlastname, custaddress)
        values (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), '', '', '')  -- put other values here (from parameters?)

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
end
```