# Can I insert data to a column in 3 different tables?

Tags: c#, sql

This is my code. I have 3 tables named

accounts, WaterDB, ElectricDB and GasDB.

-In the code below i insert information to the acounts table.

- In my accounts, WaterDB, ElectricDB and GasDB, I have a column called username.
- Is it possible for me to insert the username into the other tables 'username' column as well?

Code where i insert information to my accounts table:

```
protected void registerBtn_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["userDatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into accounts (username,email,password,postalcode,role) values (@Uname ,@email ,@pswd ,@pstlc,@role)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", registerUsernameTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", registerEmailTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pswd", registerUserPswdTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pstlc", postalCodeTB.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", role.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Loginx.aspx");
            Response.Write("Registration is successful");

            conn.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Do you have only single column in other than "accounts" tables?

Comment: No i have other columns but the only similar columns is 'username' within the 4 databases

Comment: Do you mean *3 tables* or a (similar) table in *3 databases*?

Comment: 3 tables in 1 database. Sorry i wrote wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope these  (accounts, WaterDB, ElectricDB and GasDB) are different tables in same database. Then you can run multiple insert queries in one statement

Ex:

```
string insertQuery = "insert into accounts (...) values (...); insert into othertable (...) values (...)"
```

Or you can write [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to other inserts deletes or whatever.

Or you can write a [stored procedure to insert in multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20964015/3089494) as well

Comment: He means that he has an accounts table in each of 3 databases: WaterDB, ElectricDB and GasDB.

Comment: @FrankCoyle No . , he means "3 tables in 1 database" . See his last comment in the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is how you should be handling your registration system, just answering your question.

Just create 3 connections - 1 for each database - and run the same code that you already have on each one. You can reuse a lot of the code, just change the database connection object for each one.