# Use as PK on tbl2 a PK of tbl1 with the condition when a column of tbl1 is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I want to use as primary key,
 the primary key of another table just when a condition is true.

Example

TBL1 has PK identity IdTest and two columns Nome Varchar and  HasValue Boolean

For all the HasValue True I want to create this other table TBL2 that will have IdTest as PK not identity (that is the same as TBL1) and a column Note Varchar.

Please help me as soon as u can

Comment: Found solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963961/sql-server-stored-procedure-to-insert-in-multiple-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create the table first**

```
CREATE TABLE TBL2 (
                   IDTest INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
                  ,Nome Varchar(100)
                  )
GO
```

**Populate the data**

```
INSERT INTO TBL2 (IDTest, Nome)
SELECT IDTest, Nome
FROM TBL1
WHERE HasValue = 1
```